# Flex Row Flex Wrap

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I would like to achieve something like this just by using only styles.

The flex div contains elements as follows during full width

[image]

But when the width is reduced it should behave as follows

[image]

I would like to achieve it only using styles not script. Is there any possible way of developing it in a responsive way ? Kindly help me through it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your code? What did you try? We can't just keep doing peoples codes, that's cheating yourself :)

Comment: This is not a layout that can be solved using Flexbox alone. Flexbox works for 2 dimensional layouts. Your suggested layouts are 3 dimensional, and are more suited to CSS grid layout. Check out Rachel Andrew's website https://gridbyexample.com. This will help with all manner of layout queries.